# #200 Permissions error when posting comment

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm trying to post a comment to a public post of a user using the Facebook Graph API ( 2.4 ).

I use the **publish_actions** scope for this as follows:

```
FB.login( function( r ){} , { scope : 'publish_actions', return_scopes : true } );
```

Knowing from variable `r.status` the login works fine, the permissions are given properly.

However, when I try to post a comment,

```
FB.api( "/755555337836854_906307019428351/comments", "POST", {

    message: "foo"

}, function( r ){});
```

It gives me an error ( what I know from variable `r` ) indicating a **permission error**.

```
code: 200 , message: "(#200) Permissions error"
```

Where do I fail?

Comment: what message would you want to post? what´s the benefit instead of just using facebook.com directly?

Comment: The benefit is, that we can provide an UI inside the system our users already use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**publish_actions** is a scope that Facebook has to approve for the app to use.
Starting a **submission** on the app's settings page is needed with detailful description and demo of Your app. They answer in around a week after a human tester is done with checking the app.

Afterwards this snippet works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If the permission is authorized correctly, you are most likely not allowed to post to that Graph ID with the API (755555337836854_906307019428351). I assume it is a post of a friend, and you can´t post to the wall of friends - and especially not to the wall of non-friends even if the post is public.

It would be a major spam problem if that would be allowed, because even without Login Review you could create a simple spam App for yourself.

Comment: That sounds logical. However, I am the creator, and ( the only ) administrator of the app. The app is not in sandbox mode. I am trying to comment on my public post with no comment restrictions.

Comment: can you post the link to the post?

Comment: The public post I am testing on is [this](https://www.facebook.com/Pacsiii/posts/906307019428351?pnref=story)